# How can I automatically run an android application after a given time

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I Have an application that causes several downloads, and after a while these files will grow to the point where it'll be too much to handle (fills up device storage).

Is There a way to create an application in android studio using Java that automatically runs at at given time (like at the end of the day) to delete the files. Or is my only option to make an application that Runs on boot?

Answer (score 0):

why are you handling files inside the app!!, I think all you need to do is to make a server and every time you need to do something just let the application send it to the server and the server will do all that,

check this video will let you know how to create a small server with a node.js easy way [click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oe421EPjeBE&t=18627s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org),

check this video will help you how to send REST API requests to your server [click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpEg_UVkv6E&ab_channel=yrrhelp)

and the hard work let the server do

Comment: The "application" is more of a web page that downloads files to a android tablet, but the people that will be using the tablets wont know to delete these files manually, So I wanted to create an application to put on the tablets to delete those files so I don't have to worry about the storage filling up over time